# How to detect structural database change (data files) - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Coming back with a simple question I couldn't find the answer. Is there a way (a trigger or something else) to detect structural change in a database in SQL Server?
By structural change, I mean any operation affecting **logical** and/or **physical** filename.

For example, if I add/remove a datafile to a database, I would like to launch a procedure.

I saw the "*server trigger*" operation but it does not support the "*ALTER DATABASE*" command...

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at Event Notifications and DDL Events? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453(v=sql.105).aspx  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Indeed, I just found this doc referencing all events http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522542(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sean Gallardy. Answers are in comments of first post